# How to update table with while loop in Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to update my dynamic table in while loop.

Here is my code:

```
While (@j<=@tmp_getRowCount)
Begin

Set @firstcolumn = (Select SplitFirst_tblAR from @result_AR Where rownumber = @j) //String//
Set @secondcolumn = (Select EMail_tblAR from @result_AR Where rownumber = @j)  //String//
Set @thirdcolumn = (Select SplitFirst_tblKul from @result_AR Where rownumber = @j)  //String//
Set @fourthcolumn = (Select EMail_tblKul from @result_AR Where rownumber = @j)  //String//

insert into @test Values(@tmp_ID, @firstcolumn,@secondcolumn,@thirdcolumn,@fourthcolumn)

if ((@firstcolumn = @thirdcolumn) AND (@secondcolumn != @fourthcolumn) AND (@firstcolumn != ''))
begin

Set @q_updateTable = 'Update '+ quotename(@tablename) +' Set '+@columnname+' = ''' + @fourthcolumn + ''' Where ID = ' + @tmp_ID + ''
Exec sp_executesql @q_updateTable

end

SET @j = @j+1
End
```

My result_AR table:

[image]

I know the error is in here:

> Where ID = ' + @tmp_ID + ''

When I change this Where clause as,

> Where '+@columnname+' = ''' + @secondcolumn + ''' '

code works correctly.

Why can't I set as ID my where clause? I am getting ID value as integer. 
The error is 'Query completed with errors'.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in those variables? Can you add it?

Comment: What is data type of `@tmp_ID `?

Comment: why you want while loop to do this?

Comment: @Kannan Because I have to update every row. Do you have better idea for this?

Comment: Looking at your other questions I also think this could be done with pure set-based logic. You're trying to use SQL using procedural language thinking. This solution will not scale as your dataset grows. SQL works on sets & applies transforms to every element of the set based on conditions. You can't approach it like a procedural language. Well you can, but you shouldn't ... Take the time to learn the language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can not set Id in where clause because the id is integer value and you are concatenating it with string (varchar).
So first you have to convert it in (String)varchar and the you can use it where clause.

Like :

Set @q_updateTable = 'Update '+ quotename(@tablename) +' Set '+@columnname+' = ''' + @fourthcolumn + ''' Where ID = ' + convert(varchar,@tmp_ID) + ''
Exec sp_executesql @q_updateTable

you have to use "convert(varchar,@tmp_ID)" insted of "@tmp_ID"